# Chrome DIV's with display: inline-block breaks up and down arrows

Tags: html, google-chrome, contenteditable

This just seems like it should be so simple. Chrome under Linux.

The following HTML:

```
<div contenteditable="true">
test
<div style="display: inline-block;">
    <div style="font-weight: bold">Click here. Why does down arrow now work?</div>
</div>
test
<div>
test
<div style="display: inline-block;">
    <div style="font-weight: bold">TEST2</div>
</div>
Click mouse here and press up arrow in chrome? Why does it not go up?
</div>
</div>
```

​
See http://jsfiddle.net/tSkj9/

This causes the UP and DOWN arrows to fail.

Why?

If I set it to block, up and down arrows work. Instead they move the cursor side to side by a few characters repeatedly.

I'm assuming it has something to do with inline-block in a contenteditable.

Browser bug or am I missing something about inline-block?

Comment: Definitely a browser bug. Happens in Safari too. Check the [WebKit bug tracker](https://bugs.webkit.org/) and report it if there isn't already a bug.

Comment: Thanks. I added a bug report.

Comment: Have you got a link to the WebKit bug ticket? I'd like to follow it but can't seem to find it.

Comment: I didn't know how to figure out what version of WebKit Chrome is using. But here it is:

https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=105898